# Match between two dict

Tags: ansible

This is the continuation of the previous question. I want to display just dict from lpar_proc that match with LPARNAME of validar_:

```
   "validar_": [
        {
            "LPARNAME": [
                "server1",
                "server2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": [
                "server3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    "lpar_proc": [
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server1",
            "Name": "CONT1",
            "proc": "1.05"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server2",
            "Name": "CONT1",
            "proc": "0.25"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server3",
            "Name": "CONT2",
            "proc": "0.05"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server4",
            "Name": "CONT2",
            "proc": "0.35"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server5",
            "Name": "PRD1",
            "proc": "1.15"
        }
    ]
}
```

expected output:

```
    "lpar_proc": [
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server1",
            "Name": "CONT1",
            "proc": "1.05"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server2",
            "Name": "CONT1",
            "proc": "0.25"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server3",
            "Name": "CONT2",
            "proc": "0.05"
        }
```

Im trying to use selectattr for searching inside validar_, but it doesnt display nothing. why is not working?

```
    - name: final
      debug:
        var: "{{ reserved }}"
      vars:
        reserved: "{{ lpar_proc | selectattr('LPARNAME', 'in', validar_) }}"
```

Comment: Luis, you start the question with "This is the continuation of the previous question". Can you please point to your previous question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037931/remove-an-item-from-a-list-of-dict-and-splitting-stdout-lines/72039146#72039146 @Vishwas M.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a list of list, you have to flatten all lists,
maybe there is a solution with only one task, but this playbook does the job:

```
  vars:
    validar:
      - LPARNAME:
        - server1
        - server2
      - LPARNAME:
        - server3
    lpar_proc:
      - LPARNAME: server1
        Name: CONT1
        proc: '1.05'
      - LPARNAME: server2
        Name: CONT1
        proc: '0.25'
      - LPARNAME: server3
        Name: CONT2
        proc: '0.05'
      - LPARNAME: server4
        Name: CONT2
        proc: '0.35'
      - LPARNAME: server5
        Name: PRD1
        proc: '1.15'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        clist: "{{ clist | d([]) + item.LPARNAME }}"
      loop: "{{ validar }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ reserved }}" 
      vars:
        reserved: "{{ lpar_proc | selectattr('LPARNAME', 'in', clist) }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server1",
            "Name": "CONT1",
            "proc": "1.05"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server2",
            "Name": "CONT1",
            "proc": "0.25"
        },
        {
            "LPARNAME": "server3",
            "Name": "CONT2",
            "proc": "0.05"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

you could use only one task, i am using jinja2:

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ reserved }}"
      vars:
        clist: >-
            {% set ns = namespace() %}
            {% set ns.clist = [] %}
            {% for lpar in validar %}
            {% set ns.clist =  ns.clist + lpar.LPARNAME %}
            {% endfor %}
            {{ ns.clist }}
        reserved: "{{ lpar_proc | selectattr('LPARNAME', 'in', clist) }}"
```

Comment: i didnt see i was putting on debug var instead of msg, and getting error. Im a little stress with this. Thanks

Comment: @LuisPeñafiel if you are not ok with data manipulation, i suggest you to begin to decompose the problem in multiple tasks ... after you could try to simplify the number of tasks

Comment: @LuisPeñafiel i have found a way to do only one task